# My mac laptop randomly plays music and won't stop

Tags: macbook-pro

My mac randomly plays my iTunes music while I'm watching a movie or just using my laptop. I can't stop it because iTunes is never actually open. I've tried opening iTunes and playing music but they both seem just to play over the top of each other. The only way to stop the music is to restart the laptop

Comment: It's more than odd. Did you try to scan against malware and some viruses? Let's do that first to narrow down possible circumstances.

Comment: Are you using an Apple remote?

Comment: Are you sure the music is coming from iTunes, not Spotify or other sources? Perhaps you could post a list of processes running on your computer. Open a Terminal window, and run `ps aux`. Copy the resulting output, and edit it into your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you wearing Apple EarPods/Earphones with an inline remote? If you press the center button on them anytime it will play a song from iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using your Apple TV remote? Older Mac laptops have an IR sensor that will respond to this.
If so, see "[Turn off Macbook Pro IR sensor](https://jerad.blog/turn-off-macbook-pro-ir-sensor/)" for instructions on how to disable this functionality.